# How to find a char in a map

Tags: c++

I need to create a dictionary using map .I need to create a function that display every word that start with a specific char. I create that function(start_with()) and it works ,but I want to ask if I can make it using find() and to find and display only the words that start with that char.

```
class Dictionary {
    std::map<std::string, std::string>p;
public:
    Dictionary(std::string filename) {
        std::ifstream ifstream(filename, std::ios::app);
        std::string map1, map2;
        while (ifstream) {
            ifstream >> map1>> map2;
            p.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string>(map1,map2));
        }
    }

    void start_with(char c) {
        std::string temp;
        for (auto it = p.begin(); it != p.end(); it++) {
            temp = it->first;
            if (temp[0] == c) {
                std::cout << it->first << " " << it->second << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: I suspect a string chance that [`std::map::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound) and [`std::map::upper_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/upper_bound) will come in handy for this.

Comment: Or even  [`std::equal_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::for_each` from `<algorithm>` is the solution:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> map {{"a","a"}, {"b", "b"}, {"c", "b"}};

char ch = 'b';

std::for_each (map.begin(), map.end(),
               [ch](auto e) {
                   if (e.first[0] == ch)
                       std::cout << e.first << " "
                                 << e.second << std::endl;
               }
    );
```